# Find all repeating substrings of length >= n in js

Tags: javascript, string, substring

I want to find patterns in a string for compression.

Lets say I have a string, "abcdabcr".

I want to find repeating patterns of length 2 or more, eg abc, not overlapping.

How can I do this?

I have tried searching this, but it is hard to find answers.

I have this code:

```js
function findPatterns(str) {
    let sbf=[]
    let patterns=[]
    let chunks = str.match(/.{1,2}/gm)
    chunks.forEach((c)=>{
        if (sbf.includes(c)) {
            patterns.push(c)
        }
        sbf.push(c)
    })
    return [...new Set(patterns)]
}
```

It works for finding patterns of length = 2, but not length >= 2.

Comment: Use your intuition, then give it your best shot and come back to SO when you have some working code.

Comment: The source-code for the LZ compression families has been available for decades. You've looked at some of it, right?

Comment: Yes, however I want to create my own.

Comment: If you want to create your own, why are you asking other people how to do it?

Comment: I don't want other people to create the compression algo, I am just trying to fix this.